# Como inserir o valor de um Array dentro de outro Array

Tags: javascript, funções, loop, array-push

Estou tentando separar os alunos de acordo com seus números na caderneta onde alunos nota A, seriam alunos com numeração acima de 170, alunos B alunos com numeração 160 a 169 e alunos C de numeração 150 a 159.

estou querendo que retorne no console tipo assim:
alunosA receba [170, 170, 171, 187, 191]
e com alunosB e C o mesmo.
mais nao aparece fiz como esta embaixo mais so me aparece Undefined e quando coloco no parâmetro da função as variável alunoA= ate aparece algo mais e so o mesmo numero independente da variável.

```
var numeroCardeneta = [170, 159, 151, 187, 156, 191, 165, 154, 167, 169, 171, 170, 160]

var alunosA = []
var alunosB = []
var alunosC = []

function classes(numeroCardeneta) {
    for (var i = 0; i < numeroCardeneta.length; i++){
        if (numeroCardeneta[i] >= 150 && numeroCardeneta[i] <=159){
            alunosNotaC.push(numeroCardeneta[i])
            return alunosNotaC
        } else if (numeroCardeneta[i] >= 160 && numeroCardeneta[i] <= 169){
            alunosNotaB.push(numeroCardeneta[i])
            return alunosNotaB
        } else if (numeroCardeneta[i] >= 170){
            alunosNotaA.push(numeroCardeneta[i])
            return alunosNotaA
        }
    }
}

console.log(classes(alunosNotaA))
```

Comment: Leia bem o seu próprio código,  pra que serve aquela `return` dentro de cada `if`? Você está praticamente forçando o ciclo a terminar no primeiro valor, remova todos esses `return`, além do mais você está internado sobre o array que você passa como parâmetro, o que significa que se o mesmo for vazio que é o caso do exemplo,  nada irá funcionar.  Se você precisa iterar sobre `numeroCardeneta` você não passa `alunosNotaA` como parâmetro

Comment: ok obrigado pelos conselhos, e que comecei a estudar javascript a pouco tempo. vou procurar nao erra mais nessa questao XD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema do seu código, é que você está utilizando o `return` dentro da estrutura de repetição. Isso faz com que o programa saia da função e consequentemente, interrompa o laço de repetição.

Um outro erro do código, é que você está passando como argumento para a função o array `alunosA`, array este que não possui nenhum elemento. Sendo assim, a função não retornará nenhum valor, fazendo com que a impressão seja `undefined`.

Para corrigir o problema, retire todas as declarações `return` da sua função e passe como argumento o array `numeroCardeneta`. Ou melhor ainda, no seu caso nem é preciso criar este parâmetro na função, tendo em vista que você pode acessar o array nos escopos mais internos.

Abaixo está o código corrigido:

```js
var numeroCaderneta = [170, 159, 151, 187, 156, 191, 165, 154, 167, 169, 171, 170, 160];

var alunosNotaA = [];
var alunosNotaB = [];
var alunosNotaC = [];

function definirClasses() {
    for (var i = 0; i < numeroCaderneta.length; i++){
    
        const numero = numeroCaderneta[i];
    
        if (numero >= 150 && numero <= 159) {
            alunosNotaC.push(numero);

        } else if (numero >= 160 && numero <= 169) {
            alunosNotaB.push(numero);

        } else if (numero >= 170){
            alunosNotaA.push(numero);
        }
    }
}

definirClasses();
console.log("Classe A:", alunosNotaA);
console.log("Classe B:", alunosNotaB);
console.log("Classe C:", alunosNotaC);
```

Comment: Ola obrigado pela ajuda, e peço mais uma ajudinha comecei agora a pouco a usar o stackoverflow mais teria algum artigo onde poderia me aprofundar mais ou você aconselha algum lugar para eu conseguir pegar melhor esses detalhes pois ainda sou muito leigo.